# Tensorboard got stuck in 'namespace hierarchy finding similar subgraphs'

Tags: keras, callback, tensorboard

I tried to visualize the iterative process of CNN through Tensroboard,but the browser always got stuck in 'namespace hierarchy finding similar subgraphs' and then crashes!

QAQ  Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

[Got stuck in 'namespace hierarchy finding similar subgraphs'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOKlX.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893714/tensorboard-hangs-when-visualizing-an-object-detection-graph

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

instead of:

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```